# Sum value ONLY ONCE based on ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following table:

```
ID      VALUE
1       5
1       5
1       5
2       5
2       5
3       10
3       10
3       10
```

Can someone tell me what formula would sum all values only once, based on ID?
The total would be 5+5+10 because ID 1 = 5, ID 2 = 5 and ID 3 = 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this which divides the output by the number of times found and sums them for the whole:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B9/COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9))
```

[image]

Not this only works if the value is the same for the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are `A` and `B` and row 1 holds the headers, then set `C2` to `=B2`. Now set `C3` to:

```
=IF(A3=A2,C2,C2+B3)
```

Copy this down the rest of column `C` and the last row will be the total you need.

This works only if the first column is ordered. It is implicit that all the second column values are the same for each distinct value in the first column.